# resolved Split list into parallel lists using python

Tags: python

I would like to create a parallel list from my original list and then use `sort_together`

```
original = ['4,d', '3,b']
```

parallel list should create 2 lists like this:

```
lis1 = ['4', '3'] 
list2 = ['d', 'b']
```

I've tried using `split` but was only able to obtain a single list :(

```
[i.split(",", 1) for i in original]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip(*...)` trick together with `.split`:

```
list1, list2 = zip(*(x.split(",") for x in original))
```

Now this actually gives you two `tuple`s instead of `list`s but that should be easy to fix if you really need `list`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `zip`:

```
lis1, list2 = zip(*map(lambda x:x.split(","), original))
```

- `map` will apply the function, passed as first argument (in this case, it simply splits strings on the comma separator) to every element of the `iterable` (`list` in this case) passed as second argument. After this, you'll have a `map` object which contains `['4', 'd']` and `['3', 'b']`
- the `zip` operator takes two (or more) lists and puts them side by side (like a physical zip would do), creating a lists for elements next to each other. For example, `list(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))` is `[[1.4],[2,5],[3.6]]`.
- The unpacking `*` is necessary given that you want to pass the two sublists in the returned `map` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_list = [[4,'d'], [3,'b']]
print ("initial list", str(ini_list))
res1, res2 = map(list, zip(*ini_list))
print("final lists", res1, "\n", res2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for sort and get two list

```
list1 , list2 = list(sorted(t) for t in (zip(*(item.split(',') for item in orignal))))
```

Answer (score -2):

---

```
for i in range(2):
    s[i] = sorted([oi.split(',')[i] for oi in o])
```